# Cohen's d vs. p-value

Tags: p-value, cohens-d

I recently started reading [Evidence Base Update for Autism Spectrum Disorder](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26430947).  In Table 4 they present a summary of previous work.  They use Cohen's $d$ values.

From [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3444174/)  :

$d$ = $|\frac{M_{1} - M_{2}}{\sigma}|$

where $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are the group means and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of one of the groups.  This seems a bit fraught with peril given that you have the freedom to choose the lowest $\sigma$.  It is stated that a 'large' effect would $d \gt 1.3 $.

Assuming our groups are normal distributions and using the 'canonical' value for statistical significance in the biological literature,  p-value $\lt$ 0.05, it does not seem that a $d \gt 1.3 $ would even be close to 'statistically significant.'

To get a statistically significant value (assuming $p \lt 0.05$), it seems you'd need a $d > 2.0$. I'm interpreting this as 2 $\sigma$ separation and ignoring the complications of significant discrepancies in $\sigma$ (i.e. $\sigma_{1} \gg \sigma_{2}$)

It seems that the basis for evidence in the psychological literature is even weaker than the general biological literature.

**Question** :

1. Is my interpretation of the relation to Cohen's $d$ and the p-value correct?
2. Why are they using Cohen's $d$ instead of p-values? Is this really a valid way of showing statistical significance?

Comment: Note that `cohen's d` has the denominator of `standard deviation`. While a z-statistic have the denominator of `standard error`.  So you probably couldn't infer `d > 2` purely from `p < 0.05`, you'll also need know the standard error

Answer (score 4):

Your interpretation is not correct. Cohen's *d* is a measure of effect size - basically, how many standard deviations does the outcome (e.g. executive function) change for the average treatment recipient.

The tl;dr and extremely oversimplified explanation of a p-value is that it shows how surprised you should be at seeing whatever result you had. If there were truly zero difference between groups, what is the probability that you saw the results you did, given your sample size? That's a p-value.

If you have a very small study, you need a large effect size for it to register as significant. Conversely, if you have an extremely large study, you could detect a very small effect size, e.g. a *d* of 0.05, but that effect size may not be practically significant. And that is why they were using Cohen's *d*: statistical significance and practical significance can diverge. The people doing systematic literature reviews need to consider both. Consumers of any research should consider both.

Comment: How would you interpret a rather high p-value of p=0.9 and a cohen's d=0.5 ?Is there an effect or is there none?

Comment: @Ben That means there was a difference between the groups that was not statistically significant. This probably means the study was too small (I.e. underpowered).

Comment: Thank you! So to make use of cohen's d, the p-value has to provide a significant value at first?

Comment: @Ben That may deserve a whole new question. If given a single study with those results, I'd likely say that while the study was underpowered, the phenomenon deserves further study. As part of a systematic review, as in the original question, we consider the whole body of evidence (although a very small study could've been excluded to begin with). If able to conduct a meta-analysis, a small study would provide limited information, but it does get used (unless excluded due to poor quality). I'm less certain how I'd treat this in a qualitative synthesis (again barring study exclusion).